# tabs - active property remains on all tabs after tab clicked

Tags: html, css, tabs

It would be great if one of you guys could help me resolve this issue, no matter what i try, the tabs remain active and I've no idea why!!

[image: these tabs are nested within another tab]

Here is the html:

```html
<div *ngIf="display === 'edit'" class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default animated ">
  

  <div *ngIf="!isCollapsed" class="animated fadeIn " id="details">
    <form [formGroup]="serverForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
      <div class="tabbable tabs-below">
        <div class="tab-content" style="min-height: 240px;">
  
          <!--Begin Server Tab-->
          <div class="tab-pane active col-md-12" [id]="'serverTab' + sectionId">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="display: inline-block; float: left;">             
          </div> 
    <!--End Server Tab-->

          <!--Begin Address Tab-->
          <div *ngIf="companySites.length > 0" class="tab-pane fade col-md-12" [id]="'addressTab' + sectionId">              
          </div>
          <!--End Address Tab-->

          <!--Begin Discount Tab-->
          <div *ngIf="selectedQuoteCenterCode.length > 0"     class="tab-pane fade col-md-12" [id]="'discountTab' + sectionId">
            
          </div>
          <!--End Discount Tab-->

          <!--Begin Concurrency Tab-->
          <div *ngIf="companySites.length > 0"   class="tab-pane fade col-md-12" [id]="'concurrencyTab' + sectionId">
              
          </div>
          <!--End Concurrency Tab-->

          <!--Begin View Tab-->
          <div class="tab-pane fade col-md-12" [id]="'viewTab' + sectionId">
              View Tab
          </div>
          <!--End View Tab-->
    
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a [href]="'#serverTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Server</a></li>
        <li [ngClass]="sectionAddressClass" ><a [href]="'#addressTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Address</a></li>
        <li [ngClass]="sectiondiscountClass" ><a [href]="'#discountTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Discount</a></li>
        <li [ngClass]="sectionConcurrencyClass" ><a [href]="'#concurrencyTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Concurrency</a></li>
        <li><a [href]="'#viewTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Quotes View</a></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need any more info

Using angular 4 and the this tab set is nested within another tab

Comment: The "active" class is probably added by javascript. Please post your code as text (not as image) and also include any script you have. If not, nobody will be able to answer your question.

Comment: We would need to see the code.  Your javascript is obviously adding this class, but not removing it when another tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I resolved the issue, it was due to where the active property was placed, it should have been placed on the link itself and I added the nav-link class to the link also

here is the fix in case you run into this issue:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" [href]="'#serverTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Server</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="sectionAddressClass" ><a class="nav-link" [href]="'#addressTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Address</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="sectiondiscountClass" ><a class="nav-link" [href]="'#discountTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Discount</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="sectionConcurrencyClass" ><a class="nav-link" [href]="'#concurrencyTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Concurrency</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" [href]="'#viewTab' + sectionId" data-toggle="tab">Quotes View</a></li>
  </ul>
```